# Lower bound on probability that pairwise independent Bernoulli random variables sum to 1

Tags: probability, independence, bernoulli-distribution

I'm trying to find a lower bound on the probability that $k$ pairwise independent Bernoulli random variables with $p=\frac{1}{k}$ sum to 1. The probability that they sum to $>1$ is upper bounded by $\binom{k}{2}/k^2$ (union bound), but I can't figure out how to upper bound the probability that they sum to 0, using only pairwise independence. I'm trying to come up with a constant lower bound (i.e. not depending on $k$). Chebyshev's inequality yields a $\frac{1}{k}$ lower bound. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take two extreme distributions which meet your $p=\frac1k$ and pairwise independence conditions.

---

1. Aiming for a high probability of a sum of $1$ and a low probability of a sum of $0$:

- The probability all $k$ random variables are $1$ (so with a sum of $k$) is $\frac1{k^2}$
- The probability a particular random variable is $1$ and the other $k-1$ random variables are $0$ (so with a sum of $1$) is $\frac{k-1}{k^2}$; there are $k$ cases of this
- The probability all $k$ random variables are $0$ (so with a sum of $0$) is $\frac{k-1}{k^2}$

These give a probability of the sum being $>1$ of $\frac1{k^2}$, being $=1$ of $\frac{k-1}{k}$ and being $=0$ of $\frac{k-1}{k^2}$.

---

2. Aiming for a low probability of a sum of $1$ and a high probability of a sum of $0$:

- The probability a particular pair of random variables is $1$ and the other $k-2$ random variables are $0$ (so with a sum of $2$) is $\frac{1}{k^2}$; there are ${k \choose 2}$ cases of this
- The probability a particular random variable is $1$ and the other $k-1$ random variables are $0$ (so with a sum of $1$) is $\frac{1}{k^2}$; there are $k$ cases of this
- The probability all $k$ random variables are $0$ (so with a sum of $0$) is $\frac{k-1}{2k}$

These give a probability of the sum being $>1$ of $\frac{k-1}{2k}$, being $=1$ of $\frac{1}{k}$ and being $=0$ of $\frac{k-1}{2k}$.

---

*Note that  $\frac{k-1}{2k}$ is equal to your $\binom{k}{2}/k^2$, and that your Chebyshev bound of $\frac1k$ is achieved in the second case when you have a symmetric distribution with three points of positive probability.*

Comment: You appear to equate "pairwise independent" with "independent," but the two situations differ.

Comment: @whuber - I think I did not (if I had then both examples would have had to be the same and are when $k=2$). In both examples $P(X_i=a,X_j=b)=P(X_i=a)P(X_j=b)$ for distinct $i,j$, but $P(X_i=a,X_j=b,X_k=c)\not = P(X_i=a)P(X_j=b)P(X_k=c)$  for distinct $i,j,k$,  so pairwise independence but not broader independence.  In both examples, the probability a particular pair are both $1$ is $\frac1{k^2}$ ignoring the others; in the first example the probability all the random variables are $1$ at the same time is $\frac1{k^2} \not = \frac1{k^k}$ while in the second example it is $0\not =  \frac1{k^k}$.

Comment: @whuber If there were full independence then this would have given the probabilities of the sum being $>1$ of $\frac{k^k -(2k-1)(k-1)^{k-1}}{k^k}$, being $=1$ of $\frac{k(k-1)^{k-1}}{k^k}$ and being $=0$ of $\frac{(k-1)^k}{k^k}$;  for $k>2$ these would be between the two extreme examples in my answer.

Comment: But you *are* assuming full independence for some of your calculations, such as the first bullet in #2.

Comment: @whuber: No.  For full independence, "the probability a particular pair of random variables are $1$ and the other $k−2$ random variables are $0$ (so with a sum of $2$)" is $\frac{(k-1)^{k-2}}{k^k} <\frac{1}{k^2}$.  And there would be further positive-probability cases with full independence such as the sum being $3,4,\ldots, k$, which all have probability $0$ in my second example.

Comment: @whuber ... while the $\frac1{k^2}$ in the first bullet in #2 (and in the first bullet in #1) comes from wanting pairwise independence.